# Use thread local data with PLINQ AsParallel()?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, plinq

When using `Parallel.Foreach()` there is a built in mechanism to achieve thread-local data.  I need something similar when using PLINQ `AsParallel()`.

I would like to be able to write PLINQ statements such as `list.AsParallel().ProcessElement(threadlocalresource)`.

It's possible that `ThreadLocal<T>` could help but I don't understand how to dispose the resources after the PLINQ statement completes.

I looked into the source code for `AsParallel()` in the hopes of a copy/patch to add the feature and wound up way down the rabbit hole via tons of dependencies... not really easily doable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PLINQ indeed does not have any explicit support for thread-local data. If you still think that this is the best combination for you, you can use `ThreadLocal<T>` along with its [`Values`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194898(v=vs.110).aspx) property to clean up afterwards. For example:

```
using (var threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<SomeType>())
{
    result = list.AsParallel().Select(/* use threadLocal.Value here */).ToList();

    foreach (var resource in threadLocal.Values)
    {
        resource.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: @CoderBrien [According to Reference Source, it does not.](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/ThreadLocal.cs,80de775120278afd)

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  `using()` disposes the `ThreadLocal` by releasing the references to `SomeType` objects but does not propagate the `Dispose()` call to the objects themselves.  Thanks!!!